# Html.GetEnumSelectList<DayOfWeek>() for specific culture c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there easy way to get list of days of week for specific culture?

I know how to get name of specific day for specific culture, but is there a way to easy get list of names for whole week?

I were trying to set options for html select element by:

```
asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<DayOfWeek>()"
```

But I am not seeing any way to set a specific `CultureInfo`.